# Flutter Refresh List From API

Tags: flutter

i have a GET function in my flutter code and everytime i add a new item to the list. the list doesn't refresh and won't display the newly added item unless i refresh the whole page.
this is my POST method :

```
  Future<http.Response> ajoutFournisseur(
  String numeroFournisseur,
  String addressFournisseur,
  String matriculeFiscaleFournisseur,
  String raisonSocialeFournisseur,
  String paysFournisseur,
  String villeFournisseur,
  double timberFiscaleFournisseur) async {
List fournisseurs = [];
final response = await http.post(
  Uri.parse('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/fournisseur/'),
  headers: <String, String>{
    'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
  },
  body: jsonEncode(<String, dynamic>{
    'tel': numeroFournisseur,
    'adresse': addressFournisseur,
    'mf': matriculeFiscaleFournisseur,
    'raisonSociale': raisonSocialeFournisseur,
    'pays': paysFournisseur,
    'ville': villeFournisseur,
    'timberFiscale': timberFiscaleFournisseur,
  }),
);
if (response.statusCode == 200) {
  return fournisseurs = jsonDecode(response.body);
} else {
  throw Exception('Erreur base de données!');
}
}
      Future<dynamic> future;
```

and this is code of the button to confirm :

```
ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: (() {
                    if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                      // If the form is valid, display a snackbar. In the real world,
                      // you'd often call a server or save the information in a database.
                      setState(() {
                        future = ajoutFournisseur(
                            numeroFournisseur.text,
                            addressFournisseur.text,
                            matriculeFiscaleFournisseur.text,
                            raisonSocialeFournisseur.text,
                            paysFournisseur.text,
                            villeFournisseur.text,
                            double.parse(timberFiscaleFournisseur.text));
                      });
                      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                        const SnackBar(content: Text('Ajout en cours')),
                      );
                    }
                  }), ...
```

and this is my GET methos to fetch the items from the list :

```
    fetchFournisseurs() async {
    final response =
        await http.get(Uri.parse('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/fournisseur'));

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      var items = jsonDecode(response.body);
      setState(() {
        fournisseurs = items;
        print(fournisseurs[0]['raisonSociale']);
      });
    } else {
      throw Exception('Error!');
    }
  }
.
.
.
          for (var i = 0; i < fournisseurs.length; i++)
            Card(
              child: Column(mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, children: <Widget>[
                ListTile(
                  title: Text(fournisseurs[i]['raisonSociale']), ...
```

how can i refresh the list everytime i add a new item without refreshing the whole page ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you first of all need to learn some Flutter good practices.

For example, don't put your logic into the ElevatedButton, set it into a separate Widget function like below :

```
class Test extends StatefulWidget {
  const Test({ Key? key }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Test> createState() => _TestState();
}

class _TestState extends State<Test> {
  Future<void> _handleAjout() async {
     if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
          // First, check your request succeed
          try {
            var fournisseurs = await ajoutFournisseur(
                numeroFournisseur.text,
                addressFournisseur.text,
                matriculeFiscaleFournisseur.text,
                raisonSocialeFournisseur.text,
                paysFournisseur.text,
                villeFournisseur.text,
                double.parse(timberFiscaleFournisseur.text));
           
          ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
            const SnackBar(content: Text('Ajout en cours')),
          );

          // Will only update state if no error occured
          setState(() => future = fournisseurs);
        }
        on Exception catch(e) {
          // Always make sure the request went well
          print("error");
        }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ElevatedButton(
      onPressed: (() {
       _handleAjout();
      }),
    ) 
  }
}
```

And by awaiting POST result, then you can tell your Widget to fetch data and refresh the list by making :

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return ElevatedButton(
    onPressed: (() {
      _handleAjout().then(() => fetchFournisseurs());
    }),
  ) 
}
```

The `.then` function tells Flutter to execute the code contained in the `() => myCallbackFunction()` only if the previous asynchronous function went well.

By the way, you should always check if your content looks like what you expected before calling `setState` and set data to your variables :)